# Question regarding restriction map on base for $\operatorname{Spec}A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a commutative ring with $1$ and let $f,g\in A$. In $\operatorname{Spec}A$, we have a base for the Zariski topology given by distinguished open sets $D(f)=\{P\in\operatorname{Spec}A\mid f\not\in P\}$. Given the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}$ on $\operatorname{Spec}A$, we have the isomorphism $\mathcal{O}(D(f))\cong A_f$.

The context of this question comes from proving that the distinguished open sets of $\operatorname{Spec}A$ satisfy the "gluability" condition for a sheaf on a base. We can identify a distinguished open set $D(f)=\{P\in\operatorname{Spec}A\mid f\not\in P\}$ with $A_f$, and on the overlap we have $D(f)\cap D(g)=D(fg)$.

But then given the restriction map for $\mathcal{O}$ and the association with $\mathcal{O}(D(f))$ with $A_f$ this would imply that there is a restriction map from $A_f$ to $A_{fg}$. But what would be this map? In particular, I don't see how an element of $A_f$ of the form $a/f^n$ can be thought of as an element of $A_{fg}$.

Would we just map $a/f^m$ to $ag^m/f^mg^m$?

Comment: Lots of things: 1) where are you intersecting these localizations? You have to write these things as subsets of a common something to take an intersection. 2) You've got some arrows going in the wrong direction: write down the diagram of affine schemes corresponding to the inclusions here and then reverse all the arrows. You should see that the diagram you want doesn't match the diagram you're constructing - you need to find maps $A\to A_f\to ?$ and $A\to A_g\to ?$, while you're finding maps $A\to ? \to A_f$ and $A\to ?\to A_g$.

Comment: @KReiser I'm really intersecting their corresponding open sets in $\operatorname{Spec}A$, $D(f)$ and $D(g)$, which is $D(fg$), which corresponds to $A_{fg}$.

Comment: Right, but you tried to write down an intersection of _rings_, for which you need a common set that contains both rings as subsets. I'm trying to tell you that you're doing things the wrong way because there's no general recipe for producing such a thing.

Comment: @KReiser Oh yeah, I got it. We have $\mathcal{O}(D(f))\cong A_f$ NOT $D(f)\cong A_f$.

Comment: @KReiser I edited the question for clarification.

Comment: If you can divide by $fg$ you can divide by $f$ since $1/f = g/fg$. So the universal property of localizations gives you the map $A_f$ to $A_{fg}$.

Comment: @TokenToucan Of course. Thanks!