# Doubt about sheaf of regular functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Take an irreducible algebraic set $X$: $R$ will be the coordinate ring of $X$, and for an open set $U\subset X$, the sheaf of regular functions on $U$ will be $O_X(U)$. Moreover I will indicate the disjoint open sets as $X_f$, for $f\in R$.

I know for sure that $O_X(X_f)=R_f$, and that if $U_1\subset U_2$ (with $U_1,U_2\subset X$ open sets) then $O_X(U_2)\subset O_X(U_1)$. So suppose to have $f,g\in R$, and take $X_f$ and $X_{fg}$: we know that $O_X(X_{fg})=R_{fg}$, and that $O_X(X_f)=R_f$. However $R_f$ is not contained in $R_{fg}$, as it should be since $X_{fg}\subset X_f$. I feel like this should be a simple problem to solve, but I can't see what I'm missing. Can you help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a natural map $R_f \to R_{fg}$ sending $\frac{1}{f} \mapsto \frac{g}{fg}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783354/question-regarding-restriction-map-on-base-for-operatornamespeca